# which statistical test to apply

Tags: hypothesis-testing

My data consists of body mass measures in 4 groups, each treated with different chemical and one being control group. Each group was measured after 7,14,21 and 28 days.

Which statistical test should I apply here?
(I was thinking repeated measures ANOVA, but am not sure, and don't know exactly how to implement this in R)

Comment: What is the research question? Is there any statistical hypothesis related to it?

Comment: does any of the tested compounds change body mass.
But i'm also interested can I even ask and answer a question of, wheather any group is peaking with it's body mass at some point, instead of staying flat (I know I can do this by eye, but beside this, can I just select this one time point and do anova + tukey ?)

Comment: I would think longitudinal analysis via GEE regression would be appropriate for this.  GEE makes no assumption about equal spacing of follow-up times, so you can have measurements at different days.  Model adjustments for baseline values, time, and clustering on ID to adjust for within subject correlation will strengthen identification of the treatment*time interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to account for mass measured at baseline. I presume that your hypothesis concerns whether the chemical leads to lower or higher mass at follow up. To test this hypothesis, you can use an ANCOVA. Adjust for baseline mass and repeated measures of mass at follow up, controlling for time as well as a treatment indicator. To account for correlated observations, use a random effect for repeated measures within individuals. Test the significance of treatment using the likelihood ratio test or other test.